# React Cannot read property 'map'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using react hooks and I want to display each `count` that comes from API. But I'm getting error `Cannot read property 'map'`

API return json data like:

```
model: {
  item 1: {
    count: 200
  }
  item2: {
    count: 300
  }
  item 3: {
    count: 400
  }
}
```

and `useEffect` looks like:

```
const [results, setResults] = useStates();

 useEffects(() => {
fetch('api)
.then(results =>{
    return results.json();
}).then(data => {
    let test = data.results.map((item) => {
        return(
            <div>{test.count}</div>
        );
    });
    setResults(test);
});
});
```

Comment: `.map()` is a function present only in arrays and not objects.

Comment: kindly console what do you get in data!

Comment: As `map` is a function of arrays, you can try using someting like `Object.entries`, `Object.values`

Comment: It looks like you made a typo in the code, could you correct it please? `fetch('api)`

Comment: @Dharman and `useEffects`, `useStates`

Comment: May be you are getting data.results undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` and `Array.map()` like so:

```js
const data = {
  model: {
    item1: {
      count: 200
    },
    item2: {
      count: 300
    },
    item3: {
      count: 400
    }
  }
};

console.log(Object.values(data.model).map(({
  count
}) => count));
```

Note that you want to fetch data only on mount `useEffect(fn,[])`, and also it is not recommended to save the component itself as the state, render it depending on the data:

```
const App = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useStates([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('api')
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        setResults(Object.values(data.model).map(({ count }) => count));
      });
  }, []);

  return results.map((count,key)=> <div key={key}>{count}</div>);
};
```

Comment: Just telling, the OP is looking for a React solution, but anyway... 

Comment: Sure, just slightly updated your answer.  Hope that's alright...

Comment: @deniss If I try to print `<div>{results}</div>`, is not taking the results

Comment: I can't guess how your code looks like, make a sandbox (codesandbox.io)

Comment: Hmm, the code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-hooks-h44lo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: In the codesandbox I'm not getting this error because I'm not able to get data from the API maybe

Comment: So basically you just copied the code to the sandbox, you need to provide producible example

Comment: In fact, this is working, but for some reason, if I try to print `count` in console, the console is repeating the print all the time,

Comment: So I meant, API is calling every time without stopping

Answer (score 4):

The `.map()` is a function present only in arrays and not objects. So for your case, what you can do is, loop through the keys and iterate the object.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("api")
    .then(results => {
      return results.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      let test = Object.keys(data.results).map((item, key) => {
        return <div key={key}>{data.results[item].count}</div>;
      });
      setResults(test);
    });
});
```

And one more thing is, it's `useEffect` and `useState()`, you have left a `'`, there's no `test` variable. Don't forget to give a `key` when mapping. I have corrected all the mistakes in your code above.

Comment: I'm getting the error now: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: @alar Looks like you're not adding a condition. Can you do a check like this: `if (results) return results.json();`?

Comment: still is the same issue

Comment: @alar Can you try replicating the code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io)? I couldn't replicate your issue locally.

Comment: I can't, can't get data from the api online.